# How to connect Unity to back4app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, virtual, augmented-reality, back4app

I'm trying to create Pokemon Go type game with Unity. [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-an-app-like-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO) the link for the tutorial I follow. I'm new to unity and back4apps. I'm stuck in connecting Unity to back4app server. How to do it? Is there any video tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

You can find here a step-by-step tutorial to build a pokemon go app using Back4App:
https://docs.back4app.com/docs/new-parse-app/how-to-build-a-pokemon-go-app/

And in this link here you can find a template project already connected to Back4App:
https://github.com/back4app/pokemon-go-example

Answer (score 0):

this is the link with the instructions from parse Platform

http://docs.parseplatform.org/unity/guide/

Answer (score 0):

it has duplicate dll in unity 2020 and gives you

```
The type 'Task' exists in both 'Parse.Unity, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ff
```

you have to delete ParseUnity.dll and use https://github.com/scode-cmd/Parse-for-Unity-2018 instead

and put this for server (web hosted Parse server)
https://parseapi.back4app.com

not going to work with notification as far as I've tried to debug

```
AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.parse.ParsePushUnityHelper
```

which they're missing in the parse folder apparently, I went to use Unity's notification API itself for that matter